# Passing extra arguments with Tkinter Bindings

Tags: python, binding, arguments, tkinter

I'm trying to bind an extra argument **opt** to the following radiobuttons below. I'm trying to make it so that when **WSRB_UD** is triggered I can know which radiobutton triggered it. How do I go about this?

Snippet:

```
        self.WS.SW.SearchFrame = []
        self.WS.SW.SearchRB = []

        self.WS.RBvar  = Tkinter.IntVar()

        i = 0
        while i < 6 :

            Frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.WS.SW.OptFrame, width=125, height=22, bd=1,
                                             bg=self.WSbg)
            Frame.grid(column=0, row=4 + i)
            Frame.grid_propagate(0)

            self.WS.SW.SearchFrame.append(Frame)


            RB = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.WS.SW.SearchFrame[i], value=i, 
                               variable=self.WS.RBvar, indicatoron=0, font=self.WSfo,
                               fg=self.WSfg, activeforeground=self.WSfg, bg=self.WSbg, activebackground=self.WSbg,
                               selectcolor=self.WSbg, bd=self.WSbw)
            RB.grid()
            RB.bind( "<Enter>", self.WSRB_UD, i)
            print i

            self.WS.SW.SearchRB.append(RB)

            i = i + 1

        self.QuickLinkList= []
        self.WS_timer_count = 0

    def WSRB_UD(self, event, opt):
        print self.WS.RBvar.get()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [tkinter: Specifying arguments for a function that's called when you press a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297336/tkinter-specifying-arguments-for-a-function-thats-called-when-you-press-a-butto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lambda to define an anonymous partial function:

```
RB.bind( "<Enter>", lambda event: self.WSRB_UD(event, i) )
```

You could also use `functools.partial` if you don't like the lambda syntax.