# Trying to get which Radiobutton triggered an event

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a set of radiobuttons in Tkinter. One of the attributes I'd really like to have is the ability to tell which radiobutton was last entered. I tried to bind to each radiobutton. However when the event is triggered it returns the same value each time.

What am I doing wrong?

snippet:

```
        i = 0
        while i < 5 :

            Frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.WS.SW.OptFrame, width=125, height=22, bd=1,
                                             bg=self.WSbg)
            Frame.grid(column=0, row=4 + i)
            Frame.grid_propagate(0)

            self.WS.SW.SearchFrame.append(Frame)


            RB = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.WS.SW.SearchFrame[i], value=i, #command=self.WSRB_UD,
                               variable=self.WS.RBvar, indicatoron=0, font=self.WSfo,
                               fg=self.WSfg, activeforeground=self.WSfg, bg=self.WSbg, activebackground=self.WSbg,
                               selectcolor=self.WSbg, bd=self.WSbw)
            RB.grid()
            RB.bind( "<Enter>", lambda event: self.WSRB_UD(event, i))


            self.WS.SW.SearchRB.append(RB)
            i = i + 1

        self.QuickLinkList= []
        self.WS_timer_count = 0

    def WSRB_UD(self, event, opt):
        m = self.WS.SW.SearchRB[opt-1].cget("value")
        print m
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing extra arguments with Tkinter Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419101/passing-extra-arguments-with-tkinter-bindings)

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of a question you asked two hours prior, and that is a nearly exact duplicate of other questions on this site. Why not do a little searching for the answer before asking a second time?

Comment: The difference is that I implemented the lambda function in this snippet, however for some reason it only binds to the last value i holds. I'm trying to assign i a difference value in each binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda needs to be something like this:

```
lambda event, i=i: self.WSRB_UD(event, i))
```

This creates a local variable `i` inside the lambda that is bound to the value of i at the time the binding was created.