# Python Tkinter keyboard using bind

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, bind

I have a problem using the bind option so I can click a button in my keyboard,
and call a function once the key is pressed.
I tried taking other codes that have the similar purpose and I saw that I'm doing pretty much the same, though I still have some problem I must've missed. 
I will be very thankful if you help me with this.
Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Imports
from Tkinter import *        
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
import tkMessageBox

#===========================================================================================================================================#
#Tkinter Class
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

#===========================================================================================================================================#
#Game Pieces Classes
class Board:
    def __init__(self, rows = 7, columns = 6, picture_height = None, picture_width = None):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\Ariel\Desktop\Python\4inarow.gif"))
        self.picture_height = self.picture.height()
        self.picture_width = self.picture.width()

    def create_and_pack(self, canvas):
        board_item = canvas.create_image(700, 370, image = self.picture)

    def __str__(self):
        print "Rows:", self.rows, "Columns:", self.columns

class Disk:
    def __init__(self, player_number = None):
        self.picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:\Users\Ariel\Desktop\Python\me" + str(player_number) + ".gif"))
        self.player_number = player_number

    def create_and_pack(self, canvas, x, y):
        disk_item = canvas.create_image(x, y, image = self.picture)

    def get_x_parameter(self, number):
        #X growing by 70~73 per number
        x = 330
        for i in range(7):
            if number == i:
                x = x + i * 72
        return x

    def get_y_parameter(self, number):
        #Y lowered by 70~73 per number
        y = 635
        for i in range(6):
            if number == i:
                y = y - i * 72
        return y

    def place(self, canvas, x, y):
        #First left down circle parameters
        #480, 635
        canvas.move(self.picture, x, y)

    def __str__(self):
        print "The disk's picture string:", self.picture, "The player disk's number:", self.player_number

#===========================================================================================================================================#
#Game Class 
class Game:
    def __init__(self, board = None, disk1 = None, disk2 = None):
        self.disk1 = disk1
        self.disk2 = disk2
        self.board = board

#===========================================================================================================================================#
#KeyboardClass
class Keyboard:
    def __init__(self, key_number = None):
        self.key_number = key_number

    def press_and_place(self, canvas, number, function):
    canvas.focus_set()
    canvas.bind("<" + str(number) + ">", function)

#===========================================================================================================================================#
#Main.
myapp = App()
myapp.master.title("4 in a Row")
myapp.master.maxsize(2000, 1200)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
GameBoard = Board(7, 6)
FirstPlayerDisk = Disk(1)
SecondPlayerDisk = Disk(2)
GameClass = Game(GameBoard, FirstPlayerDisk, SecondPlayerDisk)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#Creating Canvas and placing the disks and the board.
board_canvas = Canvas(width = GameBoard.picture_width, height = GameBoard.picture_height)
board_canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

GameBoard.create_and_pack(board_canvas)
FirstPlayerDisk.create_and_pack(board_canvas, 330, 635)
SecondPlayerDisk.create_and_pack(board_canvas, 260, 635)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#Creating Keyboard instance and placing the first disk in the last row in a column of choice
number_choice = 3
KeyboardClass = Keyboard(number_choice)

first_player_x = FirstPlayerDisk.get_x_parameter(number_choice)
first_player_y = FirstPlayerDisk.get_y_parameter(number_choice)
KeyboardClass.press_and_place(board_canvas, number_choice, FirstPlayerDisk.place(board_canvas, first_player_x, first_player_y))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

myapp.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem lies in this line:

```
KeyboardClass.press_and_place(board_canvas, number_choice, FirstPlayerDisk.place(board_canvas, first_player_x, first_player_y))
```

the third argument `FirstPlayerDisk.place(board_canvas, first_player_x, first_player_y)` is actually a `None` type as

```
def place(self, canvas, x, y):
    #First left down circle parameters
    #480, 635
    canvas.move(self.picture, x, y)
```

returns None

From [How to bind a keypress to a button in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832909/how-to-bind-a-keypress-to-a-button-in-tkinter) and [this site](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216830/tkinter-keypress-event-python), you need to pass the function, that is, simply `FirstPlayerDisk.place` (no parenthesis following it).

Comment: I changed the code, thank you very much, but then I get the following error : "place() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given). And you said that if I give any arguments, it'll be referred as to None. #Matthew

Comment: Yes, you will need to pass the argument with the now bound keys. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419101/passing-extra-arguments-with-tkinter-bindings) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296893/how-to-pass-an-argument-to-event-handler-in-tkinter) for some pointers